# EF Core context open connection after a using statement closes it

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

In a .NET core web api app I'm using ef core in a function that i have to run some raw sql then when I try to use the context after the raw sql it fails.

the context is passed from the from controller to logic files(actual business 
code) is a private readonly
I've tried opening the connection again but that fails.

```cs
DbConnection conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
using (conn)
{
   await conn.OpenAsync();
   using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
      //Raw SQL                
   }
}
Table1 t1 = await _context.Table1
      .Where(i => i.id == 1)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Everything works fine until the app gets to the `Table1 t1` line then i get the error

The error I get is

`InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()`

Edit

I'm asking is there a best practice way to run raw SQL that returns data that is not mapped to an entity then continue to use EF Core. Also sometimes my raw SQL is only returning a string or decimal value

Edit #2

Thanks for the help I'll be using the suggestion made by
[Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638224/ef-core-context-open-connection-after-a-using-statement-closes-it#comment99875738_56638314)

Updated working Code

```cs
DbConnection conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
await context.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   //Raw SQL                
}
context.Database.CloseConnection();
Table1 t1 = await _context.Table1
      .Where(i => i.id == 1)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: As far as returning data not mapped to an entity, check out Query Types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types

Answer (score 1):

You are `using` the connection which calls `Dispose` and closes the connection at the end of the `using` block. There's no need for that `using` at all, simply remove it. However, it seems like you are trying to run a raw SQL command on the database, EF Core has this ability already built in, for example:

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("DELETE FROM SomeTable");
```

There are also some [`FromSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) methods specific to `DbSet`s.

Comment: That only returns a `1 or 0` if the statement was successful my raw SQL returns a table that is manipulated only in this function and is not an entity.

Comment: Regardless of that, you still don't need to put the connection in a using block, let EF manage that object.

Comment: Not only *not need*, but **must not**. `Get` is not `Create`, so the caller is not owning the returned object in order to `Dispose` it.

Comment: okay so EF will close connection once the API request is finished I didn't know that so I can open the connection use ADO.NET and EF will close the connection? Thanks for the info. I'm coming from a .NET 3.5 app and first time using EF Core

Comment: Yes, unless you manually pass in the connection to EF, which can be done with a different constructor, EF will manage the connection for you. Though opening the connection might confuse EF, not sure how that will work as what you are doing is quite unusual. Perhaps our resident ED super-expert @IvanStoev knows?

Comment: It's allowed to manually open/close the connection, e.g. `_context.Database.OpenConnection();`, `_context.Database.CloseConnection();`.  `GetDbConnection()` exists only to allow creating external `DbCommand`s as in OP example. Just don't `Dispose` it :)

Comment: @IvanStoev And opening without closing, will EF barf on that?

Comment: @DavidG Well, the good practices require if you open something, to close it after you are done :) EF Core does that automatically for its own methods, I see no good reason user code not doing the same.